# My edits bump the question, can this be avoided?

Tags: support, editing

I just noticed that when I edit my answers, for grammar, clarity or details I just thought of, the question get bumped to the top in the list of active questions.

This struck me as impolite attention-hogging on my part. Is there some way I can stop my edit from bumping the question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, edits intentionally *always* bump the question; it's part of the peer-review process that keeps the network well-groomed. As a matter of fact, there have been a number of pushes to get moderators that ability, and even they have been declined.

It's fine to bump questions with properly substantive edits, just try to rate-limit yourself so no more than ~4 posts of the top 10 on the front page are the result your edits.